# Wrong query: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, dapper

I have ASP.NET application and we use Dapper library. The code that produces the error looks as following:

```
public bool CheckIfExists(IEnumerable<long> ticketGroups, long dateId, int userId)
{
    bool bRetVal = false;
    string sql = "if exists (select * from T_TicketGroupsToChangePrice where SubTypeId = @SubTypeId and DateId = @dateId and UserId = @userId)";
    using (var conn = CreateSqlConnection())
    try
    {
        int rows = conn.Execute(sql, ticketGroups.Select(g => new { SubTypeId = g, UserId = userId, dateId }));
        if (rows > 0)
            bRetVal = true;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error", ex);
    }

    return bRetVal;
}
```

When I run the application it throws the exeption: Incorrect syntax near ')'

As you can see, there can be more tickets (IEnumerable type) with the same date and user.

I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Not an answer, but your logic appears a bit weird. You appear to be asking the db for a boolean response (if exists) but then you're evaluating the result against an expected number of rows.

Comment: Yes. If the number of returned rows greater than 0, it means the row(s) exists and method returns true. Otherwise is false. Why do you mean it's weird?

Comment: But the query you're asking the db is not 'how many rows are there?'. You're asking 'are there any rows at all?'. Different things. Just a very minor observation.

Comment: That's true. I'm asking if there is any row, but the syntax of Dapper method is like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because it is not valid SQL to start with an `if` (If you mean to use T-SQL it is, but then you have to write the entire `if` statement)

I think a simple `case` is what you need:

```
select case
       when exists (select * from T_TicketGroupsToChangePrice where SubTypeId = @SubTypeId and DateId = @dateId and UserId = @userId)
       then 1
       else 0
       end
```

Comment: The problem is Execute method returns the number of rows affected.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't notice that. Use `ExecuteScalar` then.

Comment: There's an error: Must declare the scalar variable "@SubTypeId".

Answer (score 0):

Your query "**if exists (select * from T_TicketGroupsToChangePrice where SubTypeId = @SubTypeId and DateId = @dateId and UserId = @userId)**" return some data if the table have some so for that it require something to work on. Like if else condition in programming we can modify this as :

```
if exists 
(select * from T_TicketGroupsToChangePrice where SubTypeId = @SubTypeId and DateId = @dateId and UserId = @userId) 
Print 'Have Data'
 else 
Print 'Don't Have data'
```

Rewriting your code :

```
public bool CheckIfExists(IEnumerable<long> ticketGroups, long dateId, int userId)
{
    bool bRetVal = false;
    string sql = "if exists (select * from T_TicketGroupsToChangePrice where SubTypeId = @SubTypeId and DateId = @dateId and UserId = @userId) Print '**your code to execute if exist data**' else Print '**your code to execute if doesnot exist data**'";
    using (var conn = CreateSqlConnection())
    try
    {
        int rows = conn.Execute(sql, ticketGroups.Select(g => new { SubTypeId = g, UserId = userId, DateId = dateId }));
        if (rows > 0)
            bRetVal = true;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error", ex);
    }

    return bRetVal;
}
```

this link will help you more :
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/exist-select-from-my-table

Answer (score 0):

If your result depends on the number of rows and not on what's returned from the SQL, you could try this:

```
if exists ([whatever]) select 1
```

This works, because if there are no matching values, no recordset is returned, and your affected record count is zero.

You could also try something a bit simpler:

```
select 1 
from T_TicketGroupsToChangePrice 
where SubTypeId = @SubTypeId 
  and DateId = @dateId 
  and UserId = @userId;
```

But that has the disadvantage of returning one row for however many records you have.  This could be a lot, depending on the app and the context, and in any case you don't want to pull over data that you're not going to use.

I wouldn't recommend a `CASE` statement, because `SELECT CASE EXISTS ([whatever]) THEN 1 END` will still return one record, and your affected record count will be 1 even if no records exist.

The problem with your original SQL, by the way:  The statement is incomplete.  You're saying "if exists ..." but you never finish it with the equivalent of a "then".  You need to say "if exists() select 1" or something similar.